# Django(v. 1.11.3 ) HttpResponse not returning the specified reason phrase

Tags: django

In one of my views, called via an XMLHttpRequest, I am trying to return an HttpResponse object with a status code and a reason phrase. When I make a request to that specific view, the response that I get has the specified status code but the phrase that I keep getting is "error" for when returning a 40x response type, an empty string when returning a 20x...instead of the phrase that I specify.

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def auth_validate(request):
    return HttpResponse(status=401, reason="Login failed")
```

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: The reason phrase attribute is supposed to be [`reason_phrase`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponse.reason_phrase). I can't test that now, but I'm guessing your `reason` keyword argument is being ignored.

Comment: @Rúben when using reason_phrase in this case, the initialization fails with the following message: `TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'reason_phrase'`. Looking at the HttpResponse source code, its parent(HttpResponseBase) expects a **reason** keyword argument

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do is:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
import json

def auth_validate(request):
    return HttpResponse(status=401, content=json.dumps({"message":"Login Failed"}))
```

Comment: @olfredos6 Why would you think `reason` is a valid parameter to HttpResponse?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Looking at the [django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/_modules/django/http/response/), I see that HttpResponse inherits from HttpBaseResponse which accepts such a parameter when initialized `def __init__(self, content_type=None, status=None, reason=None, charset=None):`

Comment: @Olfredos6 In my opinion reason is not getting as a json body content message. It becomes just another header to be added to the response. Therefore if what you are trying fives the status code in response. You might need to check this under something like `postman` as it would point out the `header` parameter.

Comment: @PasanChamikara using Postman, it works fine without needing to parse to JSON the reason. In fact, Postman receives the specified reason phrase. The header does not contain the reason that I specify

Answer (score 0):

Are you checking in a browser, or in a test script?  I have yet to figure out how the `HttpResponse[Base]` is converted to a string of bytes to send over the wire but if you are accessing the object directly, you need to `rsp = HttpResponse(..., reason='Bother',..)` and later `assert(rsp.reason_phrase == 'Bother')`.

`HttpResponse.reason_phrase` is a `getter` that returns a field called `HttpResponse._reason_phrase`, which is set via the `reason` parameter to the `HttpResponse.__init__()`!